# Can't margin <img> right

Tags: html, css

I will begin by saying that I were look for an solution but could not find.

I have images which should be used as headers.

```css
#bodyer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10%;
  margin-top: 80px;
  width: 80%;
  background: rgba(245, 210, 83, 0.55);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(77, 77, 77, 0.7);
}

#cataHeaders {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="bodyer">
  <img id="cataHeaders" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" />
  <img id="cataHeaders" style="position: relative; width: 360px; right: 0px;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/360x360" />
  <img id="cataHeaders" src="http://via.placeholder.com/40x40" />
  <img id="cataHeaders" style="position: relative; width: 540px; right: 0px;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/540x540" />
  <img id="cataHeaders" src="http://via.placeholder.com/40x40" />
  <img id="cataHeaders" style="position: relative; width: 450px; right: 0px;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x450" />
</div>
```

Some of them need to be margin to the right, and some of them margin to the left(default).

The pictures were prepared in advance and designed with fixed width and height
(the details in the example of width and height are the real details of those images).

I tried a few 'tricks' to margin it :
 change the position to relative, set a width, margin-right: 0px, right:0.

I'm not so expert on CSS tricks and rules, so if you can find my mistake, and help me solve it , I will be glad!

Comment: float or margin??

Comment: margin. float makes the float on same line. I need this photos as headers.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Comment: I've moved your images into `<div>`s which has the floating and given them % width. You'll need to play with the image width yourself...

```
<div id="bodyer">
    <div style="float: left; with: 48%;"><img id="cataHeaders" src="images/cataheader1.jpg" /></div>
    <div style="float: right; with: 48%;"><img id="cataHeaders" style="width: auto;" src="images/cataheader2.jpg" /></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div style="float: left; with: 48%;"><img id="cataHeaders" src="images/cataheader3.jpg" /></div>
    <div style="float: right; with: 48%;"><img id="cataHeaders" src="images/cataheader4.jpg" /></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div style="float: left; with: 48%;"><img id="cataHeaders" src="images/cataheader6.jpg" /></div>
    <div style="float: right; with: 48%;"><img id="cataHeaders" style="width: auto;" src="images/cataheader7.jpg" /></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried use float. it makes them float on same line. I need those images as blocks. Which should be used as headers .

Comment: I saw the changes, still it is too messy. I tried to add content between the images and it was messy too. I prefare  solution without float

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:right`

Learn here:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

**And do not use multiple `id`s use `class` instead `id` and in css use `.` instead `#`**

```css
#bodyer {
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10%;
  margin-top: 80px;
  width: 80%;
  background: rgba(245, 210, 83, 0.55);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(77, 77, 77,0.7);
}

.cataHeaders {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
    <div id="bodyer">
      <img class="cataHeaders" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" />
      <img class="cataHeaders" style="position: relative; width: 360px; float:right" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" />
      <img class="cataHeaders" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" />
      <img class="cataHeaders" style="position: relative; width: 540px; float:right;" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" />
      <img class="cataHeaders" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" />
      <img class="cataHeaders" style="position: relative; width: 450px; float:right;" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" />
    </div>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Comment: לא, ניסיתי להשתמשת ב_פלואט:ימין_* אבל זה מבטל את כל העניין של _דיספליי: בלוק_**.
התמונות האלה אמורות לשמש בתור כותרת.
אשמח לדון איתך בנושא בצ'אט פרטני על מנת לתוכלי לרדת לסוף דעתי.


*float:right

**display:block

Comment: ohhh. I see it after you posted your solution but if you need  any help I am here to help!

Comment: Thank you! How can I contact you peraonally?

Comment: It will be esier if you show me a picture of what you want

Answer (score 0):

The number one problem you have is that an `id` can **only be used once** (see [this article](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)).  If you have some CSS that you want to repeat for multiple blocks, you want to use a `class`.

If you change your markup like this:

```
<div id="bodyer">
  <img class="cataHeaders" src="images/cataheader1.jpg" />
  <img class="cataHeaders" style="position: relative; width: 360px; right: 0px;" src="images/cataheader2.jpg" />
  <img class="cataHeaders" src="images/cataheader3.jpg" />
  <img class="cataHeaders" style="position: relative; width: 540px; right: 0px;" src="images/cataheader4.jpg" />
  <img class="cataHeaders" src="images/cataheader6.jpg" />
  <img class="cataHeaders" style="position: relative; width: 450px; right: 0px;" src="images/cataheader7.jpg" />
</div>
```

You would address all the images in CSS like this:

```
#bodyer {
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10%;
  margin-top: 80px;
  width: 80%;
  background: rgba(245, 210, 83, 0.55);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(77, 77, 77,0.7);
}

.cataHeaders {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

Next, use consistent layout instructions.  The `right`, `left`, etc. style instructions are for absolute positioning.  With relative positioning you want to use `margin` or `padding` style instructions to add the relative amount of space between elements.

Comment: OK.
I used id because I used before class and id (this code is after a few attempts of solving this issue .cataRight additionally to this id. It was on separated CSS document. in cataRight I tried position absolute with right and left. Relative with margin , float, etc. *P.S - I understand your enlightenment about the id and class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to helpers!

Solotion:

HTML:

```css
        .cataHeaders {
      position: relative;
    }

    #head1 {
      background: url("https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg") no-repeat;
      width: 720px;
      height: 200px;
    }

    #head2 {
      background: url("https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg")no-repeat;
      width: 360px;
      height: 200px;
      margin-left: calc(100% - 360px);
    }

    #head3 {
      background: url("https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg")no-repeat;
      width: 540px;
      height: 200px;
    }

    #head4 {
      background: url("https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg")no-repeat;
      width: 540px;
      height: 200px;
      margin-left: calc(100% - 540px);
    }

    #head6 {
      background: url("https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg")no-repeat;
      width: 360px;
      height: 200px;
    }

    #head7 {
      background: url("https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg")no-repeat;
      width: 450px;
      height: 200px;
      margin-left: calc(100% - 450px);
    }
```

```html
        <div id="bodyer">
          <div class="cataHeaders" id="head1"></div>
          <div class="cataHeaders" id="head2"></div>
          <div class="cataHeaders" id="head3"></div>
          <div class="cataHeaders" id="head4"></div>
          <div class="cataHeaders" id="head6"></div>
          <div class="cataHeaders" id="head7"></div>
        </div>
```